# Accessing cache.dat through ODBC

Tags: intersystems-cache

Ok, so I am trying to extract the information from a cache.dat database sent from another business. I am trying to get at the data using the ODBC. I am able to see the globals from the samples namespace when trying to export to Access, but I can't get the data from this new database to show up.

I've tried to tackle this problem two ways. First, I simply shut down Cache, replaced the
existing database in InterSystems\TryCache\mgr\samples and restart cache. Once I restart I can see all the globals in the Management Portal from the new database. If I test the ODBC connection from the Windows ODBC administrator it connects. However, when I try to pull them into an access database using ODBC there are no tables showing up to import.

I've also tried to add the database to my Cache but it gave me the error:

ERROR #5805: ID key not unique for extent 'Config.Databases'

I tried to fool around with the values in there but to no avail. This is my first time messing with anything like this and any, ANY help would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you access the Management Portal do you see any table definitions defined for your namespace.  If not, the application was written in CacheObjectScript with no Classes created to provide Object/SQL access.  If this is the case then it could be a fair amount of work to create the classes that describe the data(global structures.)

Comment: When I go to the Management Portal and look in the Samples namespace I can see all the globals from the database that was sent to us. I can even click on view and see that data. However, when I try to export this to an access database or sql server db using the ODBC none of the tables show up...

Comment: Mat - when inside the SMP, navigate to the SQL > Schema's page for your namespace containing the new database.  Do you see any schemas/tables that represent the data you're looking at in globals?  I think Stephen is right in that you'll need to bridge that data in the globals to a cache persistent class in order to make it visible over the ODBC connection.

Comment: When I go to SQL > Schemas and go the namespace with the new database there is nothing there.

So what you are saying is that it is visible inside the Cache because it knows its own method of storing the data whereas the ODBC does not know UNLESS I make it a cache persistent class? Like I said, this is the first time that I have ever worked with this system.

Answer (score 0):

Matt,
  Did the business that provided the CACHE.DAT file indicate that you should have ODBC access to the data?
  Did they provide some document describing the data/globals?  If they provided a document that describes the globals you could create the classes that map the data.  Depending on what you want to do this could either be a resource intensive process or not.

Comment: No, they said nothing about ODBC access. I doubt that they have bridged their data to ODBC, but I can ask them now that I know more about it.

Also, No, they did not send any documentation on their globals. I think that this is going to be my next step, to ask them what documentation they have on their data. 

All I want to do is pull the data directly over to an access or sql server db and then I can go from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to directly access globals you can create a stored procedure that will do so.  You should consider the security implications before you do this - it will expose all data in the global to anyone with ODBC access.

Here is an example of a stored procedure that returns the values of up to 9 global subscripts, plus the value at that node.  You can modify it pretty easily if you need to.

```
Query OneGlobal(GlobalName As %String) As %Query(ROWSPEC = "NodeValue:%String,Sub1:%String,Sub2:%String,Sub3:%String,Sub4:%String,Sub5:%String,Sub6:%String,Sub7:%String,Sub8:%String,Sub9:%String") [SqlProc]
{
}

ClassMethod OneGlobalExecute(ByRef qHandle As %Binary, GlobalName As %String) As %Status
{
    S qHandle="^"_GlobalName
    Quit $$$OK
}

ClassMethod OneGlobalClose(ByRef qHandle As %Binary) As %Status [ PlaceAfter = OneGlobalExecute ]
{
    Quit $$$OK
}

ClassMethod OneGlobalFetch(ByRef qHandle As %Binary, ByRef Row As %List, ByRef AtEnd As %Integer = 0) As %Status [ PlaceAfter = OneGlobalExecute ]
{

    S Q=qHandle  
    S Q=$Q(@Q)  b  
    I Q="" S Row="",AtEnd=1 Q $$$OK
    S Depth=$QL(Q)
    S $LI(Row,1)=$G(@Q)
    F I=1:1:Depth S $LI(Row,I+1)=$QS(Q,I)
    F I=Depth+1:1:9 S $LI(Row,I+1)=""
    S AtEnd=0
    S qHandle=Q
    Quit $$$OK
}
```

I don't have code for you to get this from access, but for reference, to access this from python you might use (with pyodbc):

```
import pyodbc
import win32com.client
import urllib2

class CacheOdbcClient:

    connectionString="DSN=MYCACHEDSN"

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def getGlobalAsOverlyLargeList(self):
        connection=pyodbc.connect(self.connectionString)
        cursor=connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("call MyPackageName.MyClassName_OneGlobal ?","MYGLOBAL")
        list=[]
        for row in cursor :
            list.append((row.NodeValue,row.Sub1,row.Sub2,row.Sub3,row.Sub4,row.Sub5,row.Sub6,row.Sub7,row.Sub8,row.Sub9))
        return list
```